# Shell Script (bash/ksh): 20 seconds to read a variable

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, solaris-10, shell

I need to wait for an input for 20 seconds, after that myscript should continue the execution.
I've tried using `read -t20 var` however this works only on bash. I'm using ksh on Solaris 10.

Can someone help me please?

**EDIT**: 20 seconds is only an example. Let's pretend it needs to wait for 1 hour. But the guy could or could not be in front the PC to write the input, he doesn't need to wait the 1 hour to enter an input, but if he's not in front of the PC so the shell should continue the execution after waiting for some time.

Thanks!

Comment: `sleep 20 && read ${variable}` ??

Comment: 20 seconds is only an example. Let's pretend it needs to wait for 1 hour. But the guy is in front the PC to write the input, he doesn't need to wait the 1 hour.... got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this forum thread](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/17255-giving-read-standard-input-timeout.html) it has the answer in the third post.

Comment: Thanks mate it worked. I was wondering... since we're using ksh, is there a way to do this with coproccess?

Comment: The third post has `read -t` which the OP can't use. Unless you're not counting the question at that link, then the third *answer* isn't a solution. This kind of confusion is one of the reasons that it's preferred on SO to include the information from the link in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [`man ksh`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ksh-1.html):

> TMOUT
>   If set to a value greater than zero, the shell terminates if a command is not entered within the prescribed number of seconds after issuing the PS1 prompt. The shell can be compiled with a maximum bound for this value which cannot be exceeded.

I'm not sure whether this works with `read` in `ksh` on Solaris. It does work with ksh93, but that version also has `read -t`.

[This script](http://www.shelldorado.com/scripts/cmds/expiremail.ksh) includes this approach:

```
# Start the (potentially blocking) read process in the background

    (read -p && print "$REPLY" > "$Tmp") &  readpid=$!

    # Now start a "watchdog" process that will kill the reader after
    # some time:

    (
        sleep 2; kill $readpid >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
        { sleep 1; kill -1 $readpid >/dev/null 2>&1; } ||
        { sleep 1; kill -9 $readpid; }
    ) &     watchdogpid=$!

    # Now wait for the reading process to terminate. It will terminate
    # reliably, either because the read terminated, or because the
    # "watchdog" process made it terminate.

    wait $readpid

    # Now stop the watchdog:

    kill -9 $watchdogpid >/dev/null 2>&1

    REPLY=TERMINATED            # Assume the worst
    [[ -s $Tmp ]] && read < "$Tmp"
```

Comment: TMOUT is intended for interactive sessions, hence it says `after issuing the PS1 prompt`. It won't do anything in a script

Comment: @Daenyth: It works in a test script I tried (but if it times out it leaves the terminal in `-echo` state and I have to do a reset).